# list after onEndReached update data but list replace old one

Tags: react-redux, react-native, react-native-ios

> When dispatch first time it show items but after onEndReached call for more load data. it replace older data and only show new data.

here my code

**reducer.js**

```
   const FREESTORIES = 'FREESTORIES';
   const FREESTORIES_SUCCESS = 'FREESTORIES_SUCCESS';
   const FREESTORIES_FAIL = 'FREESTORIES_FAIL';

export default function reducer ( state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type){

    case FREESTORIES: {
      return { ...state, isLoading: true }
    }
    case FREESTORIES_SUCCESS: {
      let stories = state.StoriesResponded;
      if(stories !== action.result){
        return { ...state, isLoading: false, StoriesResponded: action.result }
      }
    }
    case FREESTORIES_FAIL: {
      return { ...state, isLoading: false, ErrorMessage: 'error' }
    }
default:
      return state
  }
}

export function getfreestories(page,sort,userId) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => new Promise ((resolve, reject) =>{
    dispatch({ type: FREESTORIES });
    api
      .get(`/story?page=${page}&sort=${sort}&isFree=true&userId=${userId}`)
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch({ type: FREESTORIES_SUCCESS, result: res });
        resolve();
      })
      .catch((ex) => {
        dispatch({ type: FREESTORIES_FAIL });
        reject(ex);
      });
  });
}
```

In **container.js**

```
let stories = topstories.StoriesResponded;
for(let index = 0; index< stories.length; index ++){
 storieslist.push(stories[index]);
}

 <List style={{
              flex: 1,
              marginTop: 100,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent
              }}
        enableEmptySections={true}
        dataArray={storieslist}
        renderRow={(rowData, sectionID, rowID) =>
        {
        return(
          <ListItem style={{ backgroundColor: Colors.white }}>
             <TopStoriesRow topstorieslistrow={ rowData } myWishList={this.props.myWishList} />
          </ListItem>
          );
         }
onEndReached={this.onEndReached}
renderFooter={this.renderFooter}
/>
```

to load more ..

```
onEndReached = () => {
    if (this.state.isLoadingTail) {
      return;
    }
    this.setState({
      isLoadingTail: true,
    });
    if(this.props.topstories !== null) {
      let mod = this.props.topstories.StoriesResponded.length / 2;
      this._loadMoreContentAsync(pageint + Math.floor(mod));
    }
  };

  renderFooter = () => {
    if (!this.state.isLoadingTail) {
      return <View style={styles.scrollSpinner} />;
    }
    return <ActivityIndicator style={styles.scrollSpinner} />;
  };



 async componentWillMount() {
    this._loadMoreContentAsync(pageint);
  }

_loadMoreContentAsync = async (pInt) => {
    // console.log('page count ===>>>', pInt);
    const { profileData } = this.props;
    const { store: { dispatch }} = this.context;
dispatch(getfreestories((pInt), (this.state.sort));
}
```

**All code are working. Only when update the page for next data load and the replace old data by new in list.
I had tried to push in array. but it show duplicate data also. how to manage it.
Please help thanks**

Comment: where is your storieslist declaration?

Comment: In container.js 
In render function let storieslist = []

Comment: thats the reason there is always a new list pushed instead of concatenating. please declare the variable as global and one more thing is that use state instead of variable....